# GDI objects leak

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I encounter a problem with **GDI objects** increasing. How can I solve this problem?

The `DeleteObject()` function doesn`t help.

[image: PROBLEM PICTURE]

```cpp
// Other Events

GetClientRect(hAnimationStars, &Dimensions);

AnimationStarsDC = BeginPaint(hAnimationStars, &ps);

MemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(AnimationStarsDC);
HBITMAP Bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(AnimationStarsDC, Dimensions.right, Dimensions.bottom);

SelectObject(MemoryDC, Bitmap);
SetBkMode(MemoryDC, TRANSPARENT);
FillRect(MemoryDC, &Dimensions, CreateSolidBrush(BackgroundColor));

// Draw Operations

BitBlt(AnimationStarsDC, 0, 0, Dimensions.right, Dimensions.bottom, MemoryDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

while (!DeleteDC(MemoryDC));
while (!DeleteObject(Bitmap));
    
EndPaint(hAnimationStars, &ps);

// Other Events
```

Comment: You have to deselect the bitmap out of the DC before you delete either of them.

Comment: It is not acceptable here to add SOLVED to the post title. If you got an answer from someone that helped you, you can accept the question by checking the checkmark at the top left of that question, which tells everyone that that answer solved the problem. If you found the solution yourself and want to share it, write an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. You may want to do a quick review of the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

Comment: Also you have to stop using GDI anyway.

Comment: @mic Nothing wrong with the GDI. All other alternatives look nice, on paper. Once you use any of them, you'll find that they are a lot harder to set up, harder to use, harder to manage, and—if *everything* goes well—save you one frame of latency. If the alternative you propose happens to be Direct2D then you are pretty much locked into Microsoft's C++ compiler, in C++ mode. Sorry, you cannot use Direct2D in your C program.

Comment: @IInspectable the tag is C++, not C.

Comment: @mic Great. So why do we have to stop using GDI when writing C++ programs? Please be specific.

Comment: `Direct2D` is **Hard** to use, but `GDI` is **Easy** to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to restore any object you replace with `SelectObject()` before destroying the `HDC`.  You also need to destroy the `HBRUSH` you are creating.

```
GetClientRect(hAnimationStars, &Dimensions);

HDC AnimationStarsDC = BeginPaint(hAnimationStars, &ps);

HDC MemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(AnimationStarsDC);
HBITMAP Bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(AnimationStarsDC, Dimensions.right, Dimensions.bottom);

HBITMAP oldBmp = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(MemoryDC, Bitmap); // <-- REMEMBER THE OLD BITMAP!

SetBkMode(MemoryDC, TRANSPARENT);

HBRUSH Brush = CreateSolidBrush(BackgroundColor); // <-- REMEMBER THE BRUSH YOU CREATE!
FillRect(MemoryDC, &Dimensions, Brush);
DeleteObject(CreateSolidBrush); // <-- DESTROY THE BRUSH!

// Draw Operations

BitBlt(AnimationStarsDC, 0, 0, Dimensions.right, Dimensions.bottom, MemoryDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

SelectObject(MemoryDC, oldBmp); // <-- RESTORE THE OLD BITMAP!

DeleteObject(Bitmap);
DeleteDC(MemoryDC);
    
EndPaint(hAnimationStars, &ps);
```

Comment: Alternatively, one can wrap all rendering code inside a [`SaveDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-savedc)/[`RestoreDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-restoredc) bracket. This is easier to maintain when you're dealing with lots of GDI objects. Also, solid brushes can usually be replaced with a [`DC_BRUSH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getstockobject) that you don't have to clean up.